# Local variable declaration in loop

Tags: java

When I ran the following code it gave me compile time errors.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            Test2 obj = new Test2();// Compile time error- Multiple markers at this line
        System.out.println(Test2.numCreated());
    }
}

class Test2 {
    private static long number= 0;

   
    public static long numCreated() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

But when I put a local variable declaration statement `Test2 obj= new Test2()` directly within a block everything works fine.

Can someone explain to me the reason behind this or why Java developers did this?

Comment: Just to point out that the compile time error is `Test.java:4: error: variable declaration not allowed here` (pointing at Test obj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is very smart,  if you ommit the **{ }** then the **obj** object has no reason to be declared since is out of scope immediatly

remember ommiting the **{ }** means ONLY the next line will belong to the for scope...

you mean for sure instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      Test2 obj = new Test2();
}
```

But what is scope? [here more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

scope is the enclosed area where an object is visible, in this case the object **obj** is declared inside a for loop, that means you can only work with it inside the loop and it will be ready to be GC as soon as the loop is done...

Comment: Yes i mean this...but will you please elaborate your answer..I did not get when you say Scope

Answer (score 1):

As Stated by above answer you got the point of missing the braces **{}** of for loop

Note :If you remove braces, it will only read the first line of instruction. Any additional lines will not be read. If you have more than 1 line of instruction to be executed pls use curly brace - or else exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't put the braces **{ }**, loop will only execute one statement after it. Since you are declaring obj in that particular line, it won't be of any use afterwards. So the compiler warns you in advance.

You must use **{ }** if you want to execute multiple statements and make use of variables.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       Test2 obj = new Test2();
       System.out.println(Test2.numCreated());
}
```

Now it will work properly because both statements belong to the loop and are inside the scope of the loop. After the loop is finished executing, the obj will be Garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not restricted to `for` loops. The problem is actually that the statement in your example is a "Local Variable Declaration Statement" ([jls-14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)), and specifically the following line in the specification:

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block.

Your example can be reduced to

```
if(true)
    Test2 obj;
```

which also does not compile.

As soon as you add a block, it compiles fine:

```
if(true) {
    Test2 obj;
}
```